# Getting YouTube Playlist Titles and Channel Names from HTML using a JavaScript snippet in Dev Tool Console

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I want the titles and channel names of YouTube playlists for backup purposes. I found this snippet online which does half the job, extracting the info from the HTML of the playlist page using JavaScript in Dev Tools.

console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.ytd-playlist-video-list-renderer #video-title')).map((el) => {return el.textContent.trim()}).sort().join("\n"))

This filters out all the titles of the videos and I can just copy it into a text file. The problem is I'd like the channel name to be included in each entry as well, but I don't know how to do that.

Currently it looks like this:

[Video Title 1]

[Video Title 2]

...

I want it to look something like this:

[Video Title 1] by [Channel Name 1]

[Video Title 2] by [Channel Name 2]

...

Does anyone know how to alter the snippet to achieve this?

Here's a 16-video sample playlist to test on: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLTHOlLMWEwVy2ZNmdrwRlRlVfZ8fiR_ms

Comment: Please provide which youtube playlist you're using with this code.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I'm trying to use it on several playlists, it shouldn't really matter what playlist exactly since the HTML structure is the same, right? I added a sample playlist to my post though.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ...? The channel title appears to be contained in a h1 with the id `title` - but because YT produces such shit HTML (as most major companies do), that same ID is used on other elements in the same page, so accessing this element isn't exactly trivial. Easier to access the document title - that still contains `- YouTube` after the channel name, but cutting that off as well, I'll leave up to you. `{return el.textContent.trim() + ' by ' + document.title}` should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the structure of the javascript code you posted, but, if you're interested, you can try this code instead:

```
// Videos in playlist: 
vidsInPlaylist = document.querySelectorAll(".style-scope ytd-playlist-video-renderer");

// Loop videos in playlist: 
for (var i = 0; i < vidsInPlaylist.length; i++) {
   // Print video title and channel name: 
   console.log(vidsInPlaylist[i].__templateInfo.nodeList[6].innerText + " by " + vidsInPlaylist[i].__templateInfo.nodeList[7].innerText)
}
```

With your YouTube playlist example, these are the results:

```
SNOWBOARDING WITH THE NYPD by CaseyNeistat
Make It Count by CaseyNeistat
DO WHAT YOU CAN'T by CaseyNeistat
Bike Lanes by Casey Neistat by CaseyNeistat
what would you do with $25,000? by CaseyNeistat
the surprise in South Africa by Casey Neistat by CaseyNeistat
Bike Thief 2012 by CaseyNeistat
Travel With Style - Casey Neistat for J.Crew by CaseyNeistat
Crazy German Water Park by CaseyNeistat
The Dark Side of the iPhone 5S Lines by CaseyNeistat
A Love Story 8 Years in the Making by CaseyNeistat
Black Market Takes Over the iPhone 6 Lines by CaseyNeistat
Life Explained in 27 Seconds by CaseyNeistat
The Devil's Pool by CaseyNeistat
Draw My Life - Casey Neistat by CaseyNeistat
Snowboarding New York City by CaseyNeistat
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I wonder how you came up with that? I don't really code so all I did was use the inspector to try to find the elements that include the text, what was your process of finding "__templateInfo", and was finding these specific nodeList iterations which include the text just trial and error? Stupid question probably, but I'm really clueless

Comment: @Miwu, I did inspect the elements on the website and - once I found out the text I want - I did right-click > copy js path and from that selector, then, I pasted this selector and press enter, in the results in the console tab, expand the results and identify the data you want to extract, then, right click > copy js path. Hope this explanation was clear and helps you.